# Creating Symfony project

Tags: php, apache, symfony, ubuntu

After a lot of attempts I've finally managed to get Syfony installed on a Ubuntu VM. However, my (hopefully last) hurdle I'm getting the below response when I submit this:

```
user1@Vbox:/var/www/symfony$ symfony new user1project
symfony: command not found
user1@Vbox:/var/www/symfony$
```

I would have thought this is quite a fundamental error if it can't be found - however Symfony seems to be run ok as when I run `php app/check.php` and check localhost/config.php they both report that the system is ready to run Symfony. When I go to localhost/app_dev.php I get a blank page apart from the one workd "homepage" in the upper left corner - not having used Symfony before I'm not sure if this is correct or not.

I've been working along the instructions but am stuck on this step:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html#creating-your-first-symfony-project

Comment: Did you get through the step where the `symfony` executable is copied to `/usr/local/bin` and made executable with `chmod a+x`? And when you moved the file via `mv` did you rename it from `symfony.phar` to `symfony`? In other words, it may be sitting in `/usr/local/bin` as `/usr/local/bin/symfony.phar`.

Comment: The executable is not being found in your `$PATH` environment variable -- these instructions assume that `/usr/local/bin` will be in `$PATH` (usually is), but verify that 1) you copied it to that location as instructed 2) you made it executable as instructed 3) that location is actually in your `$PATH`.  Do `echo $PATH` from the command line to see what yours is.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelBerkowski ! I had been using composer and moving that instead of Symfony.phar.

Answer (score 0):

Set symfomy execute permission

```
$ sudo chmod a+x  /usr/local/bin/symfony
```